# How to retrieve last added files programmatically from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, agora.io

I'm using the Agora SDK & RestAPI to recording  life streams and upload them on AWS S3, the sdk comes with snapshoting feature that's Im planning to use for stream thumbnails.
Both Cloud Recording and Snapshot Recording are integrated with my app and works perfectly,
the Remaining problem is that **the  snapshots are named down to the microseconds**

[Agora snapshot services image file naming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA5iL.png)

From my overview, The services works as follow, Mobile App sends data to my Server, My server make requests to the Agora API so It joins the Life Stream channel and starts snapshoting and saving the images to AWS, so I suppose it's impossible to have time synchronization between AWS, AgoraRestAPI, my Server & my mobile app.

I've gone through their [docs](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_screen_capture?platform=RESTful) and I can't find anything about retrieving the file names.

I was thinking maybe I can have **a Lambda Function that retrieves the last added file on a given bucket/folder?** but due to my lack of knowledge on AWS and Lambda functions I don't know how's that or if it's possible.

any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Lambda functions typically execute in response to an event, such as an object being uploaded to S3. Those events indicate the bucket and key of the S3 object.

Comment: Your question and requirements are unclear. Can you state _what_ you are actually wanting to achieve, rather than _how_?